# Create spring dataflow server container with local jar included

Tags: spring, docker, dockerfile, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to package spring dataflow server into a container which will contain one local jar application. Publish this into local repo, expectation is that end result is same as the normal dataflow server:
https://hub.docker.com/r/springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server
just with the local jar added.

Creating the Dockerfile to include the jar is straightforward, but I'm strugling a bit with how to register the jar into dataflow server.

I know one option is to use the RESTapi, but it feels quite complicated to start the dataflow server during the docker creation. I found documentation that application.yml might be a way to do this as well, but couldn't figure out how exactly.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/README.adoc

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

So is there a straightforward way to package a jar into dataflow server docker container?

Comment: Ok, so figuring out step by step. So obviously was thinking initially wrong about adding the jar to the built-in database, since that's memory based. So totally useless. I'm now looking into creating an entrypoint script which will import the app after lauch, so it'll be populated into the correct database in use.

Comment: Uh, the springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server doesn't have curl in it, so getting quite complex. There must be some automated way to populate apps and tasks in during the bootstrap process?

Answer (score 0):

The API is the only practical way to do it. Take a look at how we register apps with the [docker-compose](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/) installation.
Technically, you could also pre-populate the associated DB table(s), but I don’t recommend this.

Comment: ok, in the Dockerfile I need start the server, make the API calls and shutdown server.